# Elasticsearch synonym mapping going both ways?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, synonym

I have a synonym mapping in my synonyms.txt that I believe should be singularly mapping the word email to outlook.

```
email => outlook
```

When I search on the word email, I'm getting results for email and outlook, as would be expected, but when I search on the word outlook, I am getting results that have either the word outlook or email in the response.

For example, I'd do a search on Outlook and expect only responses with Outlook in the field I'm searching on, but I'm also getting results that have solely Email in the field as well.

Am I misunderstanding how this synonym mapping should be working, or is something going wrong here?

I am following the directions here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/analysis-synonym-graph-tokenfilter.html

Comment: If you're converting `email` to `outlook` when indexing, why shouldn't documents that have `email` present match `outlook` when querying? In the background the only thing indexed is `outlook`, and any occurrence of `email` would have been changed to `outlook`. Exactly what are you trying to do, and what is your current field definition?

Comment: I'm not doing the synonym mapping on indexing, this is purely used as part of the search analyzer from what I understand. So I think it should just be changing `email` to `outlook` on search, and not changing `outlook` to `email` at all

Comment: So what is your field definition then? Are you using `analyzer` or `search_analyzer`?

Comment: Was using `analyzer`, after changing to `search_analyzer` it worked as I expected it to. Thanks, hadn't read anything about the difference between the two, so that was very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to apply the transformation when querying, be sure to use `search_analyzer` (which only applies when querying / searching) and not `analyzer` (which applies both when indexing and querying).